# I need to generate a 4 digit number that is completely random, but where none of the digits equal each other

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random 

D1=str(random.randint(0,9))
D2=str(random.randint(0,9))
D3=str(random.randint(0,9))
D4=str(random.randint(0,9))

while D1!=D2 and D1!=D3 and D1!=D4 and D2!=D3 and D2!=D4 and D3!=D4:
    secret=D1+D2+D3+D4
    print(secret)
```

Once I print, it just continuously runs but I want it to stop and output just once

Comment: `print(''.join(list(map(str,random.sample(range(10),4)))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
digits = random.sample(string.digits, 4)  # ['8', '9', '0', '6']
print("".join(digits))                    # '8906'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `each_choice_different` defined below to generate, from a specified sequence `seq`, a random list of `n` choices in which no choice is repeated:

```
def each_choice_different(seq, n):
    """
    Returns a list in which each element is randomly chosen from `seq`
    and no choice is repeated.

    seq : the sequence from which to make choices
    n   : the number of choices to make (should not be greater than the
          number of elements in `seq`)
    """

    seq = list(seq)
    assert 0 < n <= len(seq)
    lst = []
    for _ in range(n):
        c = random.choice(seq)
        lst.append(c)
        seq.remove(c)
    return lst

four_digits_different = lambda : sum((d*10**i for i, d in 
    enumerate(each_choice_different(range(10), 4))))

# generate 7 random numbers; no digit in each of these numbers is repeated
print([four_digits_different() for _ in range(7)])

# I got:
# [8094, 2105, 7364, 1643, 3064, 6835, 1326]
```